# Should I use multiple databases in this situation (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design

Through my companies website, our users can make artwork requests. Currently they are just being emailed to a single person.

I have been developing a separate application we'll call it "artwork manager", that will queue these artwork requests for our in house artists, and they will be passed out accordingly.

Our company website database contains the art_request table that this other application needs access to.

The "artwork manager" application only has an artists, art_doc, and awards, tables.

Should I just add these tables to our company website, and connect to that database? Or would it be best to use a separate database for each application? They are both being hosted on the same server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't separate your databases, it will create a lot of confusion on development later. I strongly suggest merge it to one application.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will use a single database, though I really want to keep the applications separate. The company website is already huge as is, and I would like to be able to segment the artwork manager as its own application to make it easily transferrable to other companies.

Comment: if you want to separate the logic in Rails [ in case your app is really big ], think about using [Rails Engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html)